# Could not find constant name for search method

Tags: php, symfony, search, twig, repository

I made a search method that should allow me to search in a TWIG table, added custom repository method that would allow me to find the entity by specified attribute and called it in the controller function and also the script responsible for the search function with its input label in the twig file but I keep getting the "[Semantical Error] Couldn't find constant name, method App\Controller\InventaireContesController::searchConte() in C:\Users\maiez\Projet\config/routes../../src/Controller/ (which is being imported from "C:\Users\maiez\Projet\config/routes/annotations.yaml"). Make sure annotations are installed and enabled.
" error.
Please find below the script in the twig code containing the search function :

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#search').keyup(function(){
                search_table($(this).val());
            });
            function search_table(value){
                $('#sa tbody').each(function(){
                    var found = 'false';
                    $(this).each(function(){
                        if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
                        {
                            found = 'true';
                        }
                    });
                    if(found == 'true')
                    {
                        $(this).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```

This is the search input field :

```
<input id="search" class="form-control" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Rechercher..." aria-label="Search">
```

This is the custom method in the entity repository :

```
public function findContes($cnt){
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('contes')
            ->where('contes.titre LIKE :titre')
            ->setParameter('titre', '%'.$cnt.'%')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

and this is the controller method that seems not to work :

```
 /**
     * @Route ("/invContes/search", name"searchInv")
     * @param Request $request
     * @param NormalizerInterface $Normalizer
     * @return Response
     * @throws \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\ExceptionInterface
     */
    public function searchConte(Request $request, NormalizerInterface $Normalizer)
    {
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Inventairecontes::class);
        $requestString=$request->get('searchValue');
        $conte=$repository->findContes($requestString);
        $jsonContent=$Normalizer->normalize($conte,'json',['groups'=>'contes']);
        $retour = json_encode($jsonContent);
        return new JsonResponse($jsonContent);
    }
```

Imports and twig IDs are correct.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like you are missing an equal sign in the route annotation of the searchConte method: `name"searchInv"`. It should be `name="searchInv"`

Comment: Error says annotations are not enabled, are you sure it's configured correctly?

Comment: Seems more like your non of controller working? as controller has been auto config using @Route annotation. Please isolate the issue and if possible update description.

Comment: as it seems I have been missing the equal sign in the route annotation and I did not pay attention to it.